# Java rtsp stream reading with vlcj

Tags: java, rtsp, vlcj

First of all, I want to point that there is not much examples how to read rtsp stream from cameras.

So far I made working rtsp stream reading using vlcj which was quite hard, because of many problem.

To begin with creating app reading rtsp stream I needed to download VLC in **version 2.1.2** which was important in my case. Next this was adding two dependencies

vlcj library in **version 3.9.0**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
        <artifactId>vlcj</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then I had to downgrade JNA version to **version 3.5.2** so:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

With this configuration I managed to read rtsp stream with this code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        /* import .dll libraries */
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

        /* rtsp stream url */
        String mrl = "rtsp://192.168.1.1:5555/h264";
        String[] options = { ":network-caching=400" };

        /* getting MediaPlayer */
        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
        HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);

        /* infinite loop keeping stream reading alive */
        while (true) {
        }
    }
```

So far I used simple `HeadlessMediaPlayer` just for tests.

The problem I met is about huge delay between camera and my stream, because it's about 1s, which is not good. Using VLC I could set delay for 300-500ms and it was really nice, but as you see in here `String[] options = {":network-caching=400"};` my caching is set to 400. But it doesn't change a lot. Stream has too big delay. 
Anyone fixed that?

Another question is about making this rtsp stream into http stream so maybe I could use it in JavaFX, because there is a media player but it does not support rtsp stream, only HTTP.

Comment: kszulchs, have you find any more infos about your problem? I'm trying to do an mosaic viewer with JavaFX and VLCj but there aren't many examples...

Answer (score 1):

It is not always clear or consistent how those switches/options should be used.

You should always enable and check the native log to see if the option was actually applied or not.

You could try:

`String[] options = {"--network-caching", "400"};`

Sometimes those options will work on the playMedia call, but other times they must be set when you create your MediaPlayerFactory.

Also, generally speaking don't use a tight loop like `while(true)`, use `Thread.currentThread().join()` instead.